# I get errors from code copied from internet

Tags: java

I have copied some code from internet:

```
    static Random randGen = new Random();     
    int hit;
    hit = randGen.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

What I want it to do is to select a number from 1-100. However, I get an error in the first line of this code:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   -Random cannot be resolved into a type.
>   -Illegal modifier for parameter randGen; only final is permitted.
>   -Random cannot be resolved into a type.

Comment: Remove static and organize your imports.

Comment: It's getting so you can't trust anything from the Internet...

Answer (score 6):

1. **Random cannot be resolved into a type** - You need to import Random (e.g. `import java.util.Random;`).
2. **Illegal modyfier for parameter randGen; only final is premitted.** - You can't use the `static` modifier inside a method.

Comment: Where do I add the "import java.util.Random;"?

Comment: At the beginning of the file, after the package statement (if you have such, and you should) take a look here: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html

Answer (score 2):

This is what the example really meant.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Suttu1 {

    static Random randGen = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hit;
        hit = randGen.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }
}
```

If your are developing with eclipse, you can automatically import code by pressing Ctrl+Shift+O

Answer (score 0):

```
Random randGen = new Random();     
int hit;
hit = randGen.nextInt(100) + 1;
```